# iOS 11 Password AutoFill - How to find which credentials provider was selected by user within their keychain?

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully managed to get the Password Autofill working within my app, but as part of the UI flow afterwards I really need to understand which account / domain credentials provider the user selected within their keychain - NOT the actual username or password itself of course, but if the user chose to select say their amazon credentials as their username / password, i would like to somehow know that Amazon was their chosen provider - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only credentials the user can select are the ones that are associated with your website.

The user will only be able to select their Amazon credentials in an Amazon app